# Visual Studio 2017 command line tools don't work when launched from batch file

Tags: windows, visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

I am experiencing a very strange behavior, old batch file works well under windows XP. Why doesn't it work when compiling a simple file like `hello.c` under (Vs2017 + Win10) by a batch file in cmd window?

When realizing that Win10 has new security policy,，I read some articles on Microsoft's website. They recommend using the developer command-line window for command-line compilation.

Indeed, manual operation works well. But when I logged on Win10 as a super administrator and tried to run everything via a batch file,
it didn't work, just finished the environment configuration.

When running the commands in the batch file manually, everything works as expected (executable file successfully generated).
What is wrong with that?

Here is the content of the batch file:

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017  \Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
cd g:\testdir
g: 
cl TestBatFileCompile.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminary Notes**:

- *vcvars64.bat* simply calls *vcvarsall.bat* and it passes the *x64* argument to it, followed by its own (if any)
- *vcvarsall.bat* mainly sets some env vars (`set VSCMD_DEBUG=3` prior running it, for verbose output) required for the *VStudio* build tools to work. Check [[MS.Docs]: Build C/C++ code on the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2017) for more details

I enhanced / simplified  your example for more clarity:

*script.bat*:

```bat
@echo off

echo Running vcvars...
%comspec% /K "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
echo Ran vcvars: %ERRORLEVEL%

echo Running cl...
cl /nologo dummy.c /link /NOLOGO
echo Ran cl: %ERRORLEVEL%
```

*dummy.c*:

```c
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053523085>dir /b
> dummy.c
> script.bat
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053523085>script.bat
> Running vcvars...
> **********************************************************************
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.2
> ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> **********************************************************************
> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053523085>rem HMMM, SOMETHING DOESN'T SEEM QUITE RIGHT. LET'S TRY EXITING CMD...
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053523085>exit
> Ran vcvars: 0
> Running cl...
> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> Ran cl: 9009
> ```

**What happened?**

- `cmd /K` ([[MS.Docs]: Cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)) opened a new *cmd* instance, on top of the existing one (using the same window)

  - *vcvarsall* was called in this (2<sup>nd</sup>) instance, did its job and finished, and things seem to have been left in the air
- But after typing *exit*, it turns out that *cl* did run, but **in the 1<sup>st</sup> *cmd* instance** (in the background, if you will), and since the variables were not previously set by *vcvarsall*, it failed

To make things work, invoke *vcvarsall* using [[MS.Docs]: call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call):

```bat
call "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

**Output** (in a new *cmd* window):

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053523085>dir /b
> dummy.c
> script.bat
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053523085>script.bat
> Running vcvars...
> **********************************************************************
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.2
> ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> **********************************************************************
> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
> Ran vcvars: 0
> Running cl...
> dummy.c
> Ran cl: 0
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053523085>dir /b
> dummy.c
> dummy.exe
> dummy.obj
> script.bat
> ```

Comment: This method works perfectly.How to build this console program release version by CL option in batch file? It seems that only VS IDE can set ?

Comment: Yes, that's setting some of *cl* (and *link*) options (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx). I guess the required one are `/MD -DNDEBUG` (also check `/MT`) Or do it via makefiles. Or even simpler, create a *VStudio* solution and project (which should set those flags to default values) and call *devenv* (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2017) on it. But that can be a topic of another question (if not already existing).    In the meantime please mark this answer as a solution to your question, so other users are aware of it.

Comment: How do I  mark this answer as a solution for my question ?